# Realm: How to import 5 Millions objects without crashing

Tags: android, insert, realm, large-files

I have to migrate a 5 million tuples sqlite database to realm. The database will be for consultation only. I started converting the 5M tuples from sqlite to json and importing the data with createAllFromJson (). It was taking too long, so I decided to use FlatBuffer instead of json and do the import manually. The problem is that after several import iterations it returns the following exception: io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Mmap () failed: Out of memory size.
I learned that closing realm is really important for this kind of issues. So I end up building and closing a realm every time I iterate, but I still get that issue.
Doing some research I learned that realm passes really badly with long files. I assume that I have to split the file into several an query them separately.
My question is this:
How do I separate a large realm file into different small files, query them and keep the incredibly fast response?
Is splitting the right aproach?

I have only 1 RealmModel:

```
public class Owner extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    @Index
    private String name;
    @Index
    private String mix;
    @Index
    private String entry;
    @Index
    private String value;

    // ... Generated getters and setters ...
}
```

And I insert this way:

```
for (int i=0; i<flat_buffer_list.lenght(); i++){
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                                .name("owner.realm")
                                .build();
    Realm realm=Realm.getInstance(config);
    OwnerList list= flatbuffer.OwnerList.getElementAsRoot(flat_buffer_list.get(i));
    for (int i=0; i<list.lenght(); i++){
       //create the realm object an perform a realm.insert(object)
    }
    realm.close();
}
```

Comment: `Mmap () failed: Out of memory size. ` does the exception say how much space it cannot mmaped?

Comment: Yes, around 300 and 600MB.

Comment: it the data that big? if it is, then, unfortunately, it reaches the continuous virtual memory space limitation on the 32 bits device :(  it would work on 64 bits device though.

Comment: The complete exception is this: io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. mremap() failed: Out of memory old size: 304652856 new size: 335544320 in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 593.

Comment: So, Is it a good idea to split the database? In that case, what is the most eficient aproach, splitting by column (separate columns in differents .realm files) or splitting by row? Thanks for taking the time to ask.

Comment: My concern is, what takes that much of space in the database? Did you save any big binary data into the db? the efficient approach depends on what is your use case. it feels every entry takes 60 MB space (300M/5M=60M). Saving the big binary data into separated files on the FS will be much better IMO.

Comment: Sorry I think I write the wrong title, 5M stands for 5 millions tuples. And the aplication crashes in 400 megabytes but that represents the 80% of the total amount to import, so I calculate that the final realm file should be around 800 megabytes. I dont save any binary data, just text with a variable amount of len, but ultimatly less than 30. But there are 5 Millions tuples. In sqlite the same database was 1.2 GB.

Comment: 800 megabytes is more than Realm can handle on 32bits devices, although it is totally fine on 64bits device. Since the virtual memory space is fragmented, you would be able to open multiple Realm db files with size 200-300 MB at the same time. Also please notice how may 200-300MB realm db files can be opened on the 32bits devices also depends on the device's system, https://github.com/beeender/VirtualSpaceLimit this project can help to check the limits. May I ask why do you wish to have that big data on device? Maybe your apk is not designed for the normal users but for the special area only?

Comment: Yes, my apk is designed for day to day users (with huge chances of have 32b devices). I am working on reducing those 800mb. I've realized that the entropy of some columns is lower than I expected  because there are repeated values. So I im "normalizing" and cleaning the data in order to reuse some fields value. But normalizing 5 million rows is not a kid job. So far I've converted the sqlite database into a postgres database, because postgres is faster and allow more complex queries.

Comment: I think I have find my way around mmap. First I reduced and cleaned the data as much as I could. Then I splitted all the data into 2 realm files and change my RecyclerViewAdapter to match 2 RealmResults instead of 1. Finally, I queried both RealmResults async , added a changeListener and notifyDataSetChanged to my RV. The size of each realm file is around 200mb, mmap can handle that amount easely. Now I am investigating how to cancel a RealmResult.findAllAsync() thread, because I need to cancel pending queries whenever a new one is ordered. If anyone can help me I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: call `RealmResults.removeChangeListener()` will cancel the asyc query.